# How to check if one column value exists in another column value using like operator

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to look for the pattern of one column in another column and trying to extract the numbers.

My table:

```
ID        aggregatedID
-----------------------
12345     null
234567    null 
34567     null 
316645    null
ID_666    12345@20200131.000@@@|234567@20200131.000@@@|34567@20200131.000@@@|316645@20200131.000@@@
```

In my table, the first 4 ID's exist in `aggregatedID` with special character concatenation. I have to get ID i.e. `ID_666` and update the first 4 ID's where `aggregatedId` had them with a different column.

This is my expected output:

```
ID        aggregatedID    Agg_ID
--------------------------------
12345     null            ID_666   
234567    null            ID_666 
34567     null            ID_666  
316645    null            ID_666
ID_666    12345@20200131.000@@@|234567@20200131.000@@@|34567@20200131.000@@@|316645@20200131.000@@@
```

I tried with substring .i.e. extracting a number after '|' and before '@'+ first number before '@'

```
SUBSTRING(aggregatedID,CHARINDEX('|',aggregatedID)+1,LEN(aggregatedID))
```

But this returns the whole string after first '|'.

I tried to match `aggregatedID` with ID using like but not getting any data.

```
select ID, aggregatedId 
from table m
where m.aggregatedID like'%' + ID + '%'
```

Can anyone please help me what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use self inner join

```
select A.id , B.id from Tab1  A INNER JOIN 
(select * from Tab1 where agg_txt is NOT NULL ) B on B.agg_txt like '%'+ rtrim(A.id) + '%'  ;
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/TUNAV15187)